# Symfony access_control not applied 'per-host' rule

Tags: symfony, security, acl

Morning folks,

mainly i want to secure all call against a url that starts with `/api/internal`.
All endpoints that start with this path are only for internal calls, e.g. in a ajax-search box. So right me when i am wrong but i thought it would be a good idea to secure this via `host` definition in `access_roles`

I tried it with the following security.yml

```
security:

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_myproject_USER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_TEAMMANAGER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_TEAMMANAGER]

providers:
    dashboard_users:
        ldap:
            service: myproject.ldap
            # my ldap config

    custom_user_provider:
        id: myproject.factory.scale_user

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    api_internal:
        pattern: ^/api/internal
        security: true
        host: myproject.dev

    api_doc:
        pattern: ^/api/doc
        security: false

    api_login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true

    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        provider: custom_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - myproject.api_login_authenticator

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: myproject_login
            check_path: myproject_login
            service: myproject.ldap
            dn_string: 'Verbund\{username}'

        logout:
            path: myproject_logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/internal, host: myproject.dev }
```

But i get this error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in SecurityExtension.php line 481:
No authentication listener registered for firewall "api_internal".
```

Side information: In this project there a 3 different sections:

1. /api/internal/**** - should only be accessible from the website itself
2. /api/ - should be accessible via REST, is secured via JWTToken
3. the Website itself - is secured via form login and LDAP

Thankful for any help you can provide.

Max

Answer (score 0):

In order to have hosts secured, use access_control

```
access_control:
# require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

where the path is your desired host.

In order to have everything for a subhost secured use

```
 - { path: ^/admin/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

remove other firewalls than main and dev!

Please refer to http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html for more information

Comment: So you say i should only have a "dev" and a "main" firewall. But what about the other defined sections? Meanwhile i have updated my question